# meanjs generator not working with yeoman?

Tags: generator, mean-stack, meanjs

I am learning meanjs stack and try to generate an app with the meanjs generator. But I have some errors.

I type in command line : `yo meanjs`

I have the following errors :

```
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.1
0.4.1
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. meann) 
Cloning the MEAN repo.......

? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.jsjsapplicati
? What is your company/author name? meanjs
? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? Yes
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? Yes
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"5.1.0","npm":"3.3.12"})
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.2.1 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.8.1 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.10.2 should be installed with -g
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o.d.raw { dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 24684390,
  size: 1236,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:20 GMT+0100 (CET),
  mtime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:20 GMT+0100 (CET),
  ctime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:20 GMT+0100 (CET),
  birthtime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:20 GMT+0100 (CET) }
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.1.0 Exit status 1
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:15:
../../nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:7:
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/me/.node-gyp/5.1.0/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 Exit status 1
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o.d.raw { dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 24685021,
  size: 1236,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:32 GMT+0100 (CET),
  mtime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:32 GMT+0100 (CET),
  ctime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:32 GMT+0100 (CET),
  birthtime: Wed Dec 23 2015 13:41:32 GMT+0100 (CET) }
In file included from ../src/debug.cc:2:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
                             ^
1 warning and 10 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/debug/src/debug.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v47-darwin-x64/debug.node" "--module_name=debug" "--module_path=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v47-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v47-darwin-x64/debug.node --module_name=debug --module_path=/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.4.6/node-v47-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/node_modules/v8-debug
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.18
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN EPEERINVALID mongodb-core@1.2.26 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID mongodb-core@1.2.30 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/Working/MVPS/honolulu/mean/npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

Being new in meanjs stack, I don't understand what happens!

Answer (score 0):

The yo generator for version 0.4.x is still under development and very buggy.
You should use mean.js version 0.3.x which is stable. However, be aware that once version 0.4.x becomes stable you will need to re-generate your modules because the file structure has changed in version 0.4.x